# Inserting bar charts using Aspose Words for Java

Tags: java, charts, ms-word, aspose

Is there a way of creating and inserting a bar chart in a Ms Word document using Aspose Words for Java? I can't find a way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.Words for Java currently doesn't allow you to create the bar chart in Word documents. However, if you just want to add a static bar chart, you may try [Aspose.Cells for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/default.aspx) to [create bar chart and render it to image](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.cells-for-java/converting-chart-to-image.html). After that, you can add this bar chart image in Word document using Aspose.Words for Java. Do you think this might help in your scenario? If it does then you can use the following code snippet to create and render the bar chart to image:

> //Create a new Workbook.
>
> Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
>
> //Get the first worksheet.
>
> Worksheet sheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);
>
> //Set the name of worksheet
>
> sheet.setName("Data");
>
> //Get the cells collection in the sheet.
>
> Cells cells = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0).getCells();
>
> //Put some values into a cells of the Data sheet.
>
> cells.get("A1").setValue("Region");
>
> cells.get("A2").setValue("France");
>
> cells.get("A3").setValue("Germany");
>
> cells.get("A4").setValue("England");
>
> cells.get("A5").setValue("Sweden");
>
> cells.get("A6").setValue("Italy");
>
> cells.get("A7").setValue("Spain");
>
> cells.get("A8").setValue("Portugal");
>
> cells.get("B1").setValue("Sale");
>
> cells.get("B2").setValue(70000);
>
> cells.get("B3").setValue(55000);
>
> cells.get("B4").setValue(30000);
>
> cells.get("B5").setValue(40000);
>
> cells.get("B6").setValue(35000);
>
> cells.get("B7").setValue(32000);
>
> cells.get("B8").setValue(10000);
>
> //Create chart
>
> int chartIndex = sheet.getCharts().add(ChartType.COLUMN, 12, 1, 33,
>   12);
>
> Chart chart = sheet.getCharts().get(chartIndex);
>
> //Set properties of chart title
>
> chart.getTitle().setText("Sales By Region");
>
> chart.getTitle().getTextFont().setBold(true);
>
> chart.getTitle().getTextFont().setSize(12);
>
> //Set properties of nseries
>
> chart.getNSeries().add("Data!B2:B8", true);
>
> chart.getNSeries().setCategoryData("Data!A2:A8");
>
> //Set the fill colors for the series's data points (France -
>   Portugal(7 points))
>
> ChartPointCollection chartPoints =
>   chart.getNSeries().get(0).getPoints();
>
> ChartPoint point = chartPoints.get(0);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getCyan());
>
> point = chartPoints.get(1);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getBlue());
>
> point = chartPoints.get(2);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getYellow());
>
> point = chartPoints.get(3);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getRed());
>
> point = chartPoints.get(4);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getBlack());
>
> point = chartPoints.get(5);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getGreen());
>
> point = chartPoints.get(6);
>
> point.getArea().setForegroundColor(Color.getMaroon());
>
> //Set the legend invisible
>
> chart.setShowLegend(false);
>
> //Get the Chart mage
>
> ImageOrPrintOptions imgOpts = new ImageOrPrintOptions();
>
> imgOpts.setImageFormat(ImageFormat.getPng());
>
> //Save the chart image file.
>
> chart.toImage(new FileOutputStream("D:\Files\MyChartImage.png"),
>   imgOpts);

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.